# $nextTick running before previous line finished

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a `vue` `function` call which is triggered when selecting a `radio button` but it seems that my code inside my `$nextTick` is running before my previous line of code is finished. I don't want to use `setTimout` as I don't know how fast the user connection speed is.

```
findOrderer() {
    axios.post('/MY/ENDPOINT')
        .then((response) => {
            this.orderers = response.data.accounts;

            console.log('FIND_ORDER',  this.orderers)

            ...OTHER_CODE
}

rbSelected(value) {
    this.findOrderer();
    this.newOrderList = [];

    this.$nextTick(() => {
        for (var i = 0, length = this.orderers.length; i < length; i++) {
            console.log('FOR')

            if (value.srcElement.value === this.orderers[i].accountType) {
                console.log('IF')

                this.newOrderList.push(this.orderers[i]);
            }
        }

        this.$nextTick(() => {
            this.orderers = [];
            this.orderers = this.newOrderList;

            console.log('orderers',this.orderers)
        })
    })
}
```

Looking at the console log the 'FINE_ORDERER' `console.log` is inside the 'findOrderer' `function` call so I would have expected this to be on top or am I miss using the `$nextTick`

[image]

Comment: What is the code for findOrderer()?

Comment: @BryanOfEarth Added some of it to description

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

That's expected, since `findOrderer()` contains asynchronous code. An easy way is to simply return the promise from the method, and then `await` it instead of waiting for next tick:

```
findOrderer() {
    return axios.post('/MY/ENDPOINT')
        .then((response) => {
            this.orderers = response.data.accounts;
            console.log('FIND_ORDER',  this.orderers);
        });
},

rbSelected: async function(value)  {

    // Wait for async operation to complete first!
    await this.findOrderer();

    this.newOrderList = [];

    for (var i = 0, length = this.orderers.length; i < length; i++) {
        console.log('FOR')

        if (value.srcElement.value === this.orderers[i].accountType) {
            console.log('IF')

            this.newOrderList.push(this.orderers[i]);
        }
    }


    this.orderers = [];
    this.orderers = this.newOrderList;

    console.log('orderers',this.orderers)
}
```

Comment: Still getting the same issue, the code is running before the asynchronous code finished. basically then `this.orderers = []` it empties it and then re-pops with the new `array` but on screen, as this is running before the `axios` stuff finished, my list quickly displays my new list then re-pop's with the original details and this is the case using your proposed fix

Comment: @murday It is not running before the axios request is complete because we are awaiting the promise’s resolution. So I’m not sure what you’re want to achieve.